# Sharing plain text from react app to other apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a button in my site for '*share a specific link*' that for smartphones will open the android/ios popup for available app receivers for text (just like the share external on facebook):

[image: android popup]

How can I do it? I've searched and didn't find anything useful..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share text to other apps, you would have to use navigator.share

For more information, [check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-web-share-api-for-native-share-options-in-html-javascript/)